# How to multiple update rows with modal bottstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

hello guys can you help me with my problem, i want to update multiple rows with modal bootstrap

So when I check the line and press the update button, it will appear modal bootstrap and I will update from there

I'm having trouble finding the script, can you help me finish my code?

this is the explanation

[I checked the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc1iB.jpg)

[After that I press "Pindah Department" or in english "Move Departemen"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F0Pn.jpg)

this basically updates quickly, just you check the line and press the "Move Departement" button, then bootstrap capital appears and you will select the value in the dropdown to update the line

this is my view :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">Data Siswa Departemen ......</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
              <table id="emp_id" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="1%" align="center"><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" id="checkAll" name="checkAll" /></th>
                    <th width="1%" align="center">No.</th>
                    <th width="20%" align="center">Nama Lengkap</th>
                    <th width="5%" align="center">No Induk</th>
                    <th width="10%" align="center">Jenis Kelamin</th>
                    <th width="5%" align="center">PIN</th> 
                    <th width="20%" align="center">Departemen</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php 

                foreach($data as $d){

                ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <input class="childbox" width="1%" type="checkbox" name="msg[]" align="center" value="" data-userid="<?php echo $d['emp_id'] ?>"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%" align="center"><?php echo $d['emp_id']; ?></td>
                    <td class="data-check"><?php echo $d['first_name']; ?></td>
                    <td class="data-check"><?php echo $d['nik']; ?></td>
                    <td class="data-check"><?php echo $d['gender']=='0' ? 'Laki-Laki' : 'Perempuan'; ?></td>
                    <td class="data-check"><?php echo $d['pin']; ?></td>
                    <td class="data-check"><?php echo $d['dept_name']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="1%" align="center"><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" id="checkAll" name="checkAll" /></th>
                    <th width="1%" align="center">No.</th>
                    <th width="20%" align="center">Nama Lengkap</th>
                    <th width="5%" align="center">No Induk</th>
                    <th width="10%" align="center">Jenis Kelamin</th>
                    <th width="5%" align="center">PIN</th> 
                    <th width="20%" align="center">Departemen</th>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>                    
              </table>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="edit_book(<?php echo $d['emp_id'];?>)"> Move Departemen</button>
        </div>
      </div><!--end panel-->
      <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/baru/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/baru/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/baru/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function () {

          $('#emp_id').DataTable( {
              "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
          } );


      $("input[name='checkAll']").click(function() {
            var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
            $("#emp_id tr td input:checkbox").attr("checked", checked); });

      } );

      function toggle(id) { 

        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('msg[]'); 
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) { 
          checkboxes[i].checked = id.checked; 
        } 
      }


function save()
      {
        var url;
        if(save_method == 'add')
        {
            url = "<?php echo site_url('proses/book_add')?>";
        }
        else
        {
          url = "<?php echo site_url('proses/book_update')?>";
        }

         // ajax adding data to database
            $.ajax({
              url : url,
              type: "POST",
              data: prepareData(),
              dataType: "JSON",
              success: function(data)
              {
                 //if success close modal and reload ajax table
                 $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                location.reload();// for reload a page
              },
              error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
              {
                  alert('Error adding / update data');
              }
          });
      }
      </script>
      <!--modal-->
      <div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Update Departemen</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body form">
              <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="emp_id"/>
                  <div class="form-body">

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Departemen</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                          <select name="dept_id_auto" class="form-control pull-right">
                            <?php
                              foreach($groups as $c)
                              {
                                  echo '<option value="'.$c['dept_id_auto'].'">'.$c['dept_name'].'</option>';
                              }
                            ?> 
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end cols-->
  </div><!--end row-->
```

I have trouble finding the script that will be called in the "Move Departement" button

This is my controller :

```
public function pindah_departemen()
{
    // MASUKKAN PARAMETER DATA DISINI, BIASANYA HASIL DARI QUERY
    $data = array(
            'title'     => 'Pindah Departemen',
            'data' => $this->Pindah_dept_model->GetSiswa($this->input->get('filter_departemen'))
        );
    $data['groups'] = $this->Pindah_dept_model->getAllGroups();
    $this->template->load('template','proses/pindah_departemen', $data);
}

public function book_update()
{
        $data = array(
            'dept_id_auto' => $this->input->post('dept_id_auto'),
        );
        $this->Pindah_dept_model->update_departemen(array('emp_id' => $this->input->post('emp_id')), $data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}

public function ajax_edit($id)
{
    $data = $this->Pindah_dept_model->get_by_id($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

This is my Model :

```
class Pindah_dept_model extends CI_Model
{

var $table = 'emp';


public function GetSiswa($dep=NULL)
{
   $this->db->select(array('emp_id', 'first_name', 'nik', 'gender', 'pin', 'dept_name'))
    ->from('emp AS e')
    ->join('dept AS d','d.dept_id_auto = e.dept_id_auto', 'left');
    if(!empty($dep)) $this->db->where('d.dept_id_auto', $dep); 
    $data = $this->db->order_by('emp_id','ASC')->get();
    return $data->result_array();
}


public function getAllGroups()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT dept_id_auto,dept_name FROM dept');
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('emp_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}

public function update_departemen($where, $data)
{
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

please guys help me finish my code, i'm looking for a way out for my code for 2 weeks and still no results

Thanks Before

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm late or not.

You can try do something like below.

HTML

```
<label>Value 1&nbsp;<input name='checkme[]' type='checkbox' value='1'></label><br>
<label>Value 2&nbsp;<input name='checkme[]' type='checkbox' value='2'></label><br>
<label>Value 3&nbsp;<input name='checkme[]' type='checkbox' value='3'></label><br>
<label>Value 4&nbsp;<input name='checkme[]' type='checkbox' value='4'></label><br>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_form" >Open Sesame</button>

 <div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Update Departemen</h4>
            </div>
              <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-body form">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="emp_id"/>
                  <div class="form-body">

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Departemen</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                          <select name="dept_id_auto" class="form-control pull-right">
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">* This is supposed to be hidden value</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input name='list_check'>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
              </form>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

- Add hidden input, and we will get the checked value and store here later.

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#modal_form').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var vals  = $('input:checkbox[name="checkme[]"]').map(function() {
              return this.checked ? this.value : undefined;
            }).get();
  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('.modal-title').text("Open Sesame : Most code in here from bootstrap documentation. XD"); // just for fun.
  modal.find(".modal-body input[name='list_check']").val(vals);
});

$("form").on("submit",function(x){
  var val_submit = $(this).serialize(); // data to be send via ajax
  alert("POST DATA : "+val_submit+"\n This is the value you will submit. The rest you can figure it out. Use explode() to split the list_check. And update like you want it.");
  x.preventDefault();
});
});
```

- After the button to open the modal. We will get the value from checkbox name checkme[]. This data need to be explode later in your php.
- And try submit it.
- I'm not going to take all your code. you need to figure out the rest by yourself. I just prepare example code that can be use. Maybe just like you want it. :)

JSFiddle Example : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/pyb7rjdo/